# Inject code into exe

Tags: patching, injection

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask this question. I want some guide lines on this subject because I don't know how to search my problem in the internet.

I want to create an executable file which can inject code into a targeted (another) executable file and run that target. What I talking about is **not** a patched `exe`. I want that `exe` to inject the code and run the program.

Is it possible to create such executable files..? If it is, can you please tell me some guiding materials..?

ps: when I search about `injection`, I get only about `dll` injection and it is not I want.

Thank You!!

Comment: Search for code injection... You'll get dozens of articles and source code

Comment: code injection takes place at runtime, not before. Modifying a binary before it is executed = patching, which you said you are not interested in. `I want that exe to inject the code and run the program` - this does not make sense.

Comment: @SYS_V I might be using words incorrectly. But if you get the idea, I just want to make an `exe` (program 1) to run another `exe` (program 2) with my code injected. So if I delete `program 2` and run `program 1`, it will not run properly.

Comment: No, I don't get the idea. Do you understand conceptually how code injection works and what it means? Maybe you should explain why you are trying to do this.

Comment: @SYS_V we have two kinds of patching... in memory while execution and the file itself before execution. You have to make it clear what you mean by execution, 1. execution of the file or 2. execution of that particular instruction.

Comment: @SYS_V If you have played games like fallout or skyrim, there is a mod called script extender (by Ian Patterson) for those games. If you want to enable the mod, you have to run their `exe` and if you run the original `exe`, game will run without the mod (Script extender `exe` is few kilobytes in size). I want that functionality to be implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start **[here](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/processesmodules/article.php/c5767/Three-Ways-To-Inject-Your-Code-Into-Another-Process.htm)**--specifically, the third technique: "The CreateRemoteThread & WriteProcessMemory Technique". To quote:

> Another way to copy some code to another process's address space and then execute it in the context of this process involves the use of remote threads and the WriteProcessMemory API. Instead of writing a separate DLL, you copy the code to the remote process directly now—via WriteProcessMemory—and start its execution with CreateRemoteThread.

You could also use the **[WriteProcessMemory function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx)** to write bytes directly, whether it's overwriting bytes directly or **[code-caving](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20240/The-Beginners-Guide-to-Codecaves)**. There are nuances to keep in mind, though, like making sure the permissions of the memory you're writing to are set properly (read/write/execute), ala the **[Virtual* functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks!! And I was looking at your youtube channel. It is good.